# Simultaneous $S$-unit equations

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-approximation

In this question I am primarily interested in rational integers and rational primes, but the same question can be easily extended to number fields.

Let $S = \{p_1, \cdots, p_k\}$ be a finite set of rational primes. By a theorem of Evertse, Gyory, Stewart, and Tijdeman (linked [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01393743)) there are only finitely many pairs of integers $(a,b)$ such that the equation
$$\displaystyle ax + by = z \text{ } (1)$$
has more than two solutions in $S$-units $x,y,z$. Recall that an $S$-unit is a rational number whose numerator and denominator are both composed of primes in $S$ only. Their theorem relies on Schmidt's subspace theorem, so is not effective (i.e., no height bound can be given for the exceptional pairs $(a,b)$).

We say that a pair $(S, (a,b))$ with $S$ a set of rational primes and $(a,b)$ a pair of rational integers is *typical* if (1) has at most 2 solutions.

For a given positive integer $m$ and a set of pairs of integers $A_m = \{ (a_1, b_1), \cdots, (a_m, b_m)\}$ and a finite set of primes $S$, we say that $(S, A_m)$ is in *good configuration* if either of the following alternatives hold:

(i) There exists $1 \leq j \leq m$ such that $a_j x + b_j y = z$ is not solvable in $S$-integers; or

(ii) $a_i x + b_i y = z$ is solvable for all elements in $A_m$, and there exists $1 \leq j \leq m$ such that $a_j x + b_j y = z$ has at most two solutions in $S$-integers.

Is it possible to find an $m$ and a set $A_m$ such that for all but finitely many sets of primes $S$, the pair $(S, A_m)$ is in good configuration? The number of exceptions is allowed to depend on $A_m$ (and hence $m$).